# You must be registered for remote messages before calling getToken

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

Error in fcm token NativeFirebaseError: [messaging/unregistered] You must be registered for remote messages before calling getToken, see messaging().registerDeviceForRemoteMessages().

I was trying to send push notifications to an ios app in react-native and for that i use firebase cloud messaging method.Here is the code I am using --

```
`import messaging, { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

export async function requestUserPermission() {
  const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
  const enabled =
    authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
    authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;

  if (enabled) {
    console.log('Authorization status:', authStatus);

    getFcmToken();
  }
}

const getFcmToken = async() =>{
    try{
      
        const fcmToken = await messaging().getToken()
        console.log("fcm token generated" , fcmToken)
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log("Error in fcm token" , error)
        alert(error?.message)
    }
}`
```

This code supposed to give me a token but it's giving me the error.I browsed everywhere on internet but didn't get any satisfactory solution of this issue. If anyone have the solution, please help??

Comment: Do you run using iOS simulator?

Comment: yes I have tried on real device also

Comment: it will work on both simulator and device if you enabled this

Comment: How to enable it??

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by Enabling Push Notification in Xcode,
Open Xcode -> Add Capability -> Notification (Follow Screenshot)
[Check Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkDeH.jpg)